# Separate the three-digit numbers in Windows form(C # ) and return them to the original state

Tags: c#, winforms, text

In Windows Form (C #), I enter my number in the text box and separate the three digits with the following code (for better readability of the number). For example, the:

2500000 => 2,500,000

But I have a problem!

I want to do math operations (addition, multiplication, etc.) on my numbers. And I need to return my number to the first state (2500000) !?

please guide me
This is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "0";
        }
        textBox1.Text = long.Parse(textBox1.Text.Replace(",", "")).ToString("n0");
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the commas againn before parsing as a number for the math operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Text` property is a string, you will need to parse it to a number in order to make math operations. You can do this safely by calling the [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) method.

```
if (long.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var number))
{
    // number is now of type long
    number += number;
}
```

By the way, in your example you remove the commas by replacing them with an empty string, but then you put them back by calling `.ToString("n0")`.